# Modify query parameters in current GET request for new url

Tags: python, url, flask, jinja2

I access a page with the path `/mypage?a=1&b=1&c=1`.  I want to create a link to a similar url, with some parameters changed: `/mypage?a=1&b=2&c=1`, b changed from 1 to 2.  I know how to get the current arguments with `request.args`, but the structure is immutable, so I don't know how to edit them.  How do I make a new link in the Jinja template with the modified query?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Write a function that modifies the current url's query string and outputs a new url.  Add the function to the template globals using your Flask app's [`template_global`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.template_global) decorator so that it can be used in Jinja templates.

```
from flask import request
from urllib.parse import urlencode

@app.template_global()
def modify_query(**new_values):
    args = request.args.copy()
    
    for key, value in new_values.items():
        args[key] = value

    return '{}?{}'.format(request.path, urlencode(args))
```

```html
<a href="{{ modify_query(b=2) }}">Link with updated "b"</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Directly in Jinja:

```
{% set args = request.args.copy() %}
{% set _ = args.setlist("b", [2]) %}
{{ url_for(request.endpoint, **args) }}
```